# Setting up an array of char using smart pointer and std::vector

Tags: c++, char, c++17, smart-pointers

I want to have an array of `char[maxname]`. My initial approach was the following

```
 class char_list
 {
  char_list(int noc){names_.reserve(noc)}
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char>> names_;
  void setname( const char* name){ names_.push_back(name)};

 }
```

When I try to invoke the routine by e.g.

```
char aux[100];
aux = 'asadsdsd'  
const char* aux1 = aux;
setname(aux1);
```

I get the error

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char *' to
  'const std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::unique_ptr<char, std::__1::default_delete<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<char, std::__1::default_delete<char> > > >::value_type' (aka
  'const std::__1::unique_ptr<char, std::__1::default_delete<char> >') for 1st argument
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
```

I am using `clang` with C++17 standard.

Comment: Got to wonder if what you really want is `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> names_;`

Comment: `unique_ptr` is only meant for pointers that you allocate with `new`.  Trying to use it on a literal string isn't going to work.

Comment: But please post real code. The code you've posted doesn't compile for many different reasons.

Comment: With all due respect, none of this code makes much sense. What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Whatever your goal, this code is unlikely to get you closer to it.

Comment: `std::vector` already is smart in that sense that it frees memory. Just `std::vector<char>` or really, that's `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you shall banish char[] and arrays in general. Normally you are expected to use std::vector and in the case of string, use std::string. Vector grows & shrink automatically and do memory management for you. std::string does the same but is specialized for string management.

So you code would look like:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
```

Then you can do wonderful things like:

```
names.push_back("ABC");
```

And then you can easily retrieve your name:

```
std::string &name0 = names[0];
```

Or the char* equivalent(only for C interoperability):

```
const char *c_string = name0.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have an array of char[maxname]

An array of arrays is called a 2-dimensional array.

```
constexpr unsigned N = 10;  // 10 as an example.
char arr[N][maxname];
```